# How to use HelperList in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

A learn to write module in Prestashop. And i need to use `HelperList`,but have problems with it. With `HelperForm` all ok.

```
public function displayList()
{

         $this->fields_list = array(
            'id_email' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('id_email'),
                'width' => 140,
                'type' => 'int',
            ),
            'email' => array(
                'title' => $this->l('email'),
                'width' => 140,
                'type' => 'text',
            ),
        );

        $helper = new HelperList();

        $helper->shopLinkType = '';

        $helper->simple_header = false;

        $helper->actions = array('edit', 'delete', 'view');

        $helper->identifier = 'id_email';
        $helper->show_toolbar = true;
        $helper->title = 'HelperList';
        $helper->table =_DB_PREFIX_.$this->name;

        $helper->token = Tools::getAdminTokenLite('AdminModules');
        $helper->currentIndex = AdminController::$currentIndex.'&configure='.$this->name;
        return $helper;
}
```

and when i write `return $this->displayList();` in getcontent i have empty page.
What i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public function displayList() {
//$results = array(some_data)
 !!!return $helper->generateList($results,$fields_list);`

Comment: Can you kindly add some explanation as about why is this solving the problem?

Comment: The function needs to return the results of the method generateList(), not just the $helper object.